# Is there any way using azure-devops API, notify us via email if there are any changes in wiki page or If any new wiki pages created

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using Azure DevOps API, I would like to create an application with below functionality

1. When ever there are changes in azure devops wiki pages, it should notify us using an email
2. And also when ever there is new Wiki page created , it should notify us through an email.

Can somebody help on whether it is possible or not, If possible please help us with SDK and all.

I am looking for an exact API, which I need to work.

Comment: Is your wiki git based? In that case you can setup email notifications through the notifications hub

Comment: See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications

Comment: Hi @Siva Sankar, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestion in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test and try with the [**Wiki pages API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and [**Wikis API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), we seem have no such API can be used to sent email notifications when Wiki pages added or updated.

The workaround, as @jessehouwing mentioned, you can push the wiki pages as the source files of a Git repository in the project. Then you can set the email notifications for code changes in this Git repository.

You can set up a special repository for Wikis in the project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am not admin to this project. I am contributor this project.
I think we will not be able create separate wiki for this small kind of notification.
Please let me know if we can do with another way

Comment: Hi @Siva Sankar,

Currently, using notifications for code is the only workaround I can think of.

If you really need the notifications for Wiki, I recommend that you can report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

Comment: FYI.. i am looking for console automation using either PowerShell or   C#.net by using any of Azure DevOps API.